# C program passing in arguments via command line

Tags: c, command-line

I'm trying to create an extremely simple program that consists of two .c files - main.c and foo.c.

The objective is to link both these files, and pass a parameter into the main.c method, which then calls method foo() in the foo.c file.

The code for main.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    foo(argv[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

and foo.c is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void foo(char *input[]) {

    printf("Welcome, %s\n", input);
}
```

I also have a header file, foo.h which has just the line:
    void foo(char *input[]);

When I try to build and run the files using

```
gcc -o main main.c foo.c foo.h
```

I get the error

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible       pointer type [enabled by default]
foo(argv[1]);
^
In file included from main.c:2:0:
foo.h:1:6: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
void foo(char *input[]);
```

Where have I gone wrong in my code? I've been trying to play around with it for a while. Note that when I run ./main "Test", it prints Welcome, Test i.e. the correct expected output, but the warning errors bother me. Also, how can I make a simple makefile to compile these 3 files, rather than typing gcc everytime? I tried to do the following:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g


all: main foo

clean:
    rm -f main foo
```

but typing "make" doesn't compile anything.

Thanks.

Comment: **C does not support classes. There are no classes, but files**. They were also no classes in C++, btw. And - of course - the contents also does not include classes, but functions (as given).

Comment: Your error messages don't match your code at all.

Comment: Woops, have edited sorry

Answer (score 5):

I don't know where did you take this

```
void foo(char *input[]) {
    printf("Welcome, %s\n", input);
}
```

from, but it's certainly wrong.

It should be

```
void foo(char *input) {
    printf("Welcome, %s\n", input);
}
```

the type of `argv[1]` is `char *` and using `char input[]` although valid, is not necessary because it's converted to a pointer anyway, even `char input[10]` will have type `char *`, this is specially bad if you try to use the `sizeof` operator.

In my opinion, and it's just my opinion, you should never make your code Java-ish like `void foo(char input[])`, some people have an argument that states it's good to do it to know that you are passing an array to the funcion, but it doesn't matter because in the end it's just a pointer to the first element of the array anyway.

Comment: I'm confused as to why it should be *input and not *input[] when I am referring to an array of characters. I'm not sure I completely understood your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In here `void foo(char *input[])` input is array of type char pointer which should be just `void foo(char input[])`. The rule should be obeyed is the actual argument passed and the formal argument in the function called which is received should of same type.